# What's the point of having wmemcpy?

Tags: c, memory

This question applies both to C and C++.

`memcpy` basically copies raw memory from an address to another address.
So my question is: what's the point of `wmemcpy`?

I mean, it's still contiguous space, and copying it is still the same process. It shouldn't matter if it's made of up `wchar_t`'s, or should it?

Comment: It is a C function. C++ provides others features like string type and related functions

Comment: "*What's the point of having wmemcpy?*" None.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN documentation of [`wmemcpy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dswaw1wk.aspx):

> memcpy copies count bytes from src to dest; wmemcpy copies **count wide
>   characters (two bytes)**.

So the difference is on how many bytes will be copied with the given same arguments,when you say:

```
memcpy(src,dest,2);//2 bytes will be copied
wmemcpy(src,dest,2);//4 bytes,i.e 2*2 bytes will be copied
```

Other than this difference and possible convenience of use when using `wmemcpy` when copying `wchar_t` arrays, i don't think there is a difference between the two and the existence of `wmemcpy` is really necessary.

Comment: So that means `wmemcpy(src,dest,2);` is equivalent to `memcpy(src,dest,2*sizeof(wchar_t));`. It's just a convenience function?

Comment: @DeiDei I believe it is, since it copies raw bytes from source to destination.

Comment: Well yes, that's what it *does*, but that doesn't explain why it makes sense to have `wmemcpy()` when there is already `memcpy()`.

Comment: @John Bollinger Convenience of use may be? It would be rather convenient to say `wmemcpy(src,dest,2)` to copy two `wchar_t` arrays than saying `memcpy((char*)src,(char*)dest,2*sizeof(wchar_t))`. Don't you think so?

Comment: Downvoted: Does not answer the question.

Comment: @FUZxxI Should i add my last comment to the answer then?

Comment: No, actually, I don't think convenience provides much justification for this function.  Or at least, I don't see what's so special about `wchar_t` that warrants it having its own special version of `memcpy()`, when none of C's base types -- not even `char` -- has one.

Comment: @bkVnet “may be” is not an explanation. An explanation would cite an authoritative document or be extremely convincing.

Comment: @FUZxxI No it is not, it's just my opinion on the matter, as you have yours. That is why i use the word *"...possible convenience.."* in the answer. You have the right to disagree, as do i.

Answer (score 3):

Interfac will ensure you copied whole wchar_t number of symbols. You won't be able to copy odd number of bytes

Comment: With this same argument functions for the other standard types would have to exist.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this, but at least it attempts to address the question that was actually posed.